# Are $C^n$ smoothness classes defined for fractional $n$?

Tags: real-analysis, definition

Are $C^n$ smoothness classes defined for fractional $n$?

What is the definition?

Comment: There are [fractional derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus), so I could imagine that such a thing would exist.

Comment: Sobolev spaces or Hoelder spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. I didn't bother to write it out but take a look at [Hölder condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition)

EDIT: As noted in the comments Sobolev spaces are indeed a generalization. And they are nicely connected by the [Sobolev embedding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality)